# How to Delete the white pixels in an image in java

Tags: java

How can I remove the white pixels of an image before loading it in the `Panel`
the  method for loading image in panel is:

```
public  void ajouterImage(File fichierImage) {   
    // desiiner une image à l'ecran 
    try {
        monImage = ImageIO.read(fichierImage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    repaint(); 
}
```

Comment: You can't "remove" a pixel from an image.  Do you mean to change them to another color, such as black?

Comment: Do you want to make it transparent?

Comment: I want to load the image in the panel but without the white pixels because  I work with a black and white picture, I want to display in the Panel just black pixels

Comment: whene i make it transparent they take no space in the panel?

Comment: I want to select the signateur to display in the panel

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove a pixel for say from an image, but you sure can change the color of it, or even make it transparent.

Let's say you have a pixel array as a variable somewhere, and you can give it the RGB value of your `BufferedImage`. The pixel array will be called `pixels`:

```
try {
    monImage = ImageIO.read(fichierImage);
    int width = monImage.getWidth();
    int height = monImage.getHeight();
    pixels = new int[width * height];
    image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        // I used capital F's to indicate that it's the alpha value.
        if (pixels[i] == 0xFFffffff) {
            // We'll set the alpha value to 0 for to make it fully transparent.
            pixels[i] = 0x00ffffff;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I like that mixed-case hex value to distinguish alpha bits. Nice.

Comment: but in the panel the image is not displayed completely just half, 
how can I do for displaying the signateur?    I can move the image in the panel with the mouse for example??? how can i do this ??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by removing pixels you mean setting them to transparent, you need to set the alpha value of the image to zero. Here is a function `colorToAlpha(BufferedImage, Color)` which takes a `BufferedImage` and a `Color` as input and returns another `BufferedImage` with the `Color` set to transparent.

```
public static BufferedImage colorToAlpha(BufferedImage raw, Color remove)
{
    int WIDTH = raw.getWidth();
    int HEIGHT = raw.getHeight();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int pixels[]=new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    raw.getRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixels, 0, WIDTH);
    for(int i=0; i<pixels.length;i++)
    {
        if (pixels[i] == remove.getRGB()) 
        {
        pixels[i] = 0x00ffffff;
        }
    }
    image.setRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixels, 0, WIDTH);
    return image;
}
```

Example usage:

```
BufferedImage processed = colorToAlpha(rawImage, Color.WHITE)
```